# How to set ID or css selector for new row added in table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a code which is used to add new row to the table,see the code below

```
$("#example tbody tr").each(function(i, object) {       
        var safeHtml= gwt.@com.my.sample.client.gwt.GWTExpandCollapse::getRowValue(I)(i);//Calling GWT Java Method which return HTML                
         $(object).after(safeHtml); //Inserting new row     
        //How to assign (ID or CSS) to the above inserted row
    });
```

The above code is working fine,but i need to assign (ID or CSS Selector) to the newly inserted row,I search it but didn't find any clue.How to do this using Javascript?Any Help?

Note:see the below image,the newly row which is added might contain any think inside the row.
[image]

Comment: how newly inserted row looks like? Can you show markup for it?

Comment: can you show value of variable `safeHtml` before you call `$(object).after(safeHtml);`

Comment: safeHtml can be any think like "<tr ><td>Full name:'"+i+"'</td><td></td></tr>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the css selector using the below code,

```
$("#example tbody tr").each(function(i, object) {       
        var safeHtml= gwt.@com.my.sample.client.gwt.GWTExpandCollapse::getRowValue(I)(i);             
         $(object).after(safeHtml); //Inserting new row     
         $(object).next().addClass("hideShow");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .attr()

```
    $("#example tbody tr").each(function(i, object) {       
        var safeHtml= gwt.@com.my.sample.client.gwt.GWTExpandCollapse::getRowValue(I)(i);//Calling GWT Java Method which return HTML     
        var newSafeHtml = $.parseHTML(new String(safeHtml.toString()).replace("<tr>", "<tr id='item"+i.toString()+"'>"));
         $(object).after(newSafeHtml); //Inserting new row
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Nilay..i tried but its adding id to the above row

Comment: $(object).attr('id', "item" + i.toString() ); is adding attr to old row not to the new row

Comment: Oh, yes. sorry, i  am updating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81390/discussion-between-mohammed-sameen-and-nilay-vishwakarma).

Comment: the above solution is not working(id is not adding to the new row)..any other clue

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g0phwzq7/)

html

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
.yourclassname1 {
    color:red;
}
.yourclassname2 {
    color:green;
}
```

jquery

```
var i = 1;
$("tr").each(function () {
    var safeHtml = '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>';
    $(this).after(safeHtml);
    $(this).next().addClass("yourclassname"+i);
    i = i+1;
});
```